# Can I set a Psychiatry to only cure patients rather than diagnose?

Tags: two-point-hospital

Patients keep going to my psychiatry for diagnosis, getting in the way of patients who need to be cured there. Is there a way to set a psychiatry/ward to only be used for curing (or only for diagnosis)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think at the time you asked the question, there was no way to do this, but now you can set psychiatry, wards and DNA labs to be diagnosis or treatment only.

[image: UI showing room stats and buttons]

Answer (score 2):

A Psychiatry is a combination diagnosis/treatment room.  You can't stop it from being used for both purposes.  Building another one just splits the patients between them.

The best you can do is ensuring it's used as little as possible by giving your Psychiatry doctors as many of the Psychiatry skills as possible; it bumps up their ability to diagnose and treat all patients they see.  You can also train them in Motivation, which adds another 10% to their efficiency, turning it into a revolving door for all those Mock Star emergencies.